# JavaScript: toString

Tags: javascript, scope, window, tostring

How come `Object.prototype.toString === toString`? If I have this in the global scope:

```
var toStringValue = toString.call("foobaz");
```

I would expect `toStringValue` to be the value of `window.toString` because `window` is the default scope, right? How come `toString` by itself resolves to `Object.prototype.toString` instead of `window.toString`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results you'll get will be dependent on the host environment. If I run this:

```
alert(toString === window.toString);
alert(toString === Object.prototype.toString);​
```

...on Chrome I get `true` and `false`, respectively; on Firefox I get `false` and `false`. IE gives `true` and `false` **but** see below.

The window object on browsers is a bit tricky, because it's a host object, and host objects can do strange things if they want to. :-) For instance, your `toString.call("foobaz")` will fail on IE, because the `toString` of `window` is not a real JavaScript function and doesn't have `call` or `apply`. (I'm not saying it's right to be that way, you understand...)

Comment: Is this why frameworks tend to cache `Object.prototype.toString` locally?

Comment: @Jeremy: No, they do that just to save looking it up all the time (`Object.prototype.toString` is two property lookups and potentially a bunch of scope traversals/lookups); grabbing the value to a local can be much faster, and more concise). They want a handy reference to it because `Object.prototype.toString` is one of the ways to figure out what an object is. Details: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html